# How to embed RTSP video feed on website?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp, transcoding

I'm creating website which needs video stream from surveillance camera implemented. Camera is GeoVision GV-FD120D 1.3Mpix LowLux IR 2.7-9mm and it is linked to server which I have full access to (I dont have direct access to camera)

I was playing around with settings on this cam and I managed to turn on RTSP protocol access for this camera. Then I used VLC (on server) to open network stream with address: rtsp://192.168.0.12:8554/CH001.sdp. Works!
So far all good. Now...

Ideally I would like to show the video in player like [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) , however it does not support RTSP protocol, but RTMP instead.

So I guess I would need some kind of software on this server to:

1) transcode the video stream from RTSP -> RTMP

2) stream it out from server so I can connect to it with jwplayer later

I heard of Wowza media server but the budget is pretty tight for this project so would rather use free solution here.

Really looking for any pointers how to make this work,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your budget for this project is low. I would suggest [DORGEM](http://dorgem.sourceforge.net/)

Its an Open Source project (sadly, they have stopped working on this project for further developments , but their features will work for you), Just download their Tool from the above link and you can just record your stream from webcam and upload it to your FTP and do many other options.

Mark it as answer if you like this answer for this post.

You can try the tool and if you experience errors you can post a new thread here. Thanks.